# How to render html file?

Tags: external-command

I've the following sample html code:

```
vim http://example.com/
```

Is there any way to actually render html inside vim editor?
In example using markdown formatting or something similar?

Example scenario: I'm logged on remote machine when I don't have access to GUI and I'd like to check how the html code looks like without opening external web browsers.

Comment: Why use Vim, and not text based web browser? Such as `lynx`, `links`, `elinks`, or `w3m`? Vim is a text editor, not a web browser ... you can do this from within Vim even, with `:!lynx %`

Comment: There are some external tools for converting HTML to Markdown. [This vimcasts episode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-external-filter-commands-to-reformat-html/) shows how to use pandoc, which may suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering html can be implemented by using a text-based web browser which can extract a formatted view of the text from an html file or a web page.

In example:

```
:!links -dump %
:!elinks -dump %
:!lynx -dump %
:!w3m -dump %
```

To define your own html preview command, try:

```
:command! ViewHtml execute ':!links -dump %'
:ViewHtml
```

Then you can associate this custom command with some key for easier access, by e.g.:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>H :ViewHtml<CR>
```

then pressing <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> will preview html of the current file.

To preview current file in separate window or to open hyperlinks, you may try to use the following code:

```
function! ViewHtmlText(url)
  if !empty(a:url)
    new
    setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
    execute 'r !elinks ' . a:url . ' -dump -dump-width ' . winwidth(0)
    1d
  endif
endfunction
" Save and view text for current html file.
nnoremap <Leader>H :update<Bar>call ViewHtmlText(expand('%:p'))<CR>
" View text for visually selected url.
vnoremap <Leader>h y:call ViewHtmlText(@@)<CR>
" View text for URL from clipboard.
" On Linux, use @* for current selection or @+ for text in clipboard.
nnoremap <Leader>h :call ViewHtmlText(@+)<CR>
```

<sup>Source: [vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preview_current_HTML_file)</sup>

Using above code, you can press <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to save and preview the current file. To preview currently selected hyperlink, press <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>.

Related:

- [Preview current HTML file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preview_current_HTML_file) at vim wikia
- [Is there a way to dynamically examine html output with vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371674/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-examine-html-output-with-vim) at stackoverflow SE

Answer (score 9):

Not really. Vim's rendering engine is not designed for this sort of thing. It just renders text.

However, you could use a text-mode browser such as [`w3m`](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) to turn your HTML into text and then load that into vim. Create a new buffer and use `:r !` (see `:help :r`) to read in the result of the `w3m` conversion:

```
:r !w3m -dump your-html-file.html
```